# How to prevent desktop browser (Chrome, Safari) from zooming a webpage

Tags: html, css, web, zooming

I have tried using the following meta view port tag to prevent browser zooming:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,target-densitydpi=device-dpi' name='viewport' />
```

This doesn't work though. I know that it is possible because my zooming is blocked on this website: [futurism.xyz](http://futurism.xyz/)

The viewport tag for that website is this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: `user-scalable` is mobile only.. Specifically, I belive it's iOS Safari and Android Chrome only. Also, I can [zoom just fine](http://i.imgur.com/sL6zsic.png) on that link you provided (Chrome 57). That said, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/995914/4824627) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27116221/4824627) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22053915/4824627), they might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent zoom cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```

or this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use css.

```css
body {
    touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        Content here...
    </body>
</html>
```

[More information here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action)

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

I searched for it as well, try this one, found it inside a bootstrap template =)

Answer (score -1):

You have a lot of options in your tag. maybe some options rule the other out?
try to strip down the options to a few as possible.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Should be enough. Eventually add `user-scalable=no` also.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: It looks like it does'nt exist a cross browser solution for desktop browsers. have you seen this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser . Then, disabling zoom for desktop users is not recommended.

Answer (score -5):

It's all wrong because they are skids.

Use these (must be both or wont work)

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport'/>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```